# Multiple Email Blurbs

Tags: docusignapi

This is the text I want:

Dear XXX,

Blah blah blah blah blah.

-LINK TO SIGN THE DOCUMENT-

Regards,
YYY

Is there a way to display the docusign link inside the email blurb? All the values I'm using are dynamic, so I can't hard code anything into the resource file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, with the new Docusign Signing Experience the button/link appears at the top of the email and this works perfectly for me.